# Passing request parameters on an API fetch Request

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, fetch-api

How do I pass down parameters to a fetch request? I have this api call to fetch the logged in users username. How do I pass the returned results to the other fetch request route as it's request parameter?

```
//Gets logged in user's username

async function getProfile(){
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${SUMMIT_API}/users/myprofile`,{
      method: 'GET',  
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${myToken}`
      },
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data.profile
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Oops Something Went Wrong! Could not get that user profile.');
  }


}
```

Results from above fetch:
[image]

```
//Request parameters is the logged in user's username in the route retrieved from above fetch request


async function userChannel(){
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${SUMMIT_API}/users/myprofile/**${username}**/channel`,{
      method: 'GET',  
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${myToken}`
      }
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data.profile;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Oops Something Went Wrong! Could not render userChannel');
  }


}
```

How do I get the information from first request passed to the second?

Comment: Are you simply looking to do `var profile = await getProfile(); var username = profile[0].username;` at the beginning of `userChannel`?

Comment: Not sure, I will try that, I just want the returned username, to be passed in to the other fetch as it's parameter. How do I extract that out of the results?

Comment: That was what I needed, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the information you want seems to be supplied by your `async function getProfile`, it seems like you simply need to `await getProfile()` and pull the necessary information out:

```
var profile = await getProfile();
var username = profile[0].username;
```